# How update record picklist field from a variable in a flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, picklist

I'm trying to found a solution for this one. I've a flow in place that creates or updates a record based on some criteria.

On record creation or update, I'm assigning a value to a picklist field. This value is coming from a variable TEXT within the flow.

the picklist field is called Relation_Type__c and the picklist item which I'm trying to assign is called "Wife". It does exist in Relation_Type__c

The debug returns an error:
Error Occurred: The flow tried to update these records: null. This error occurred: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST: Relation Type: bad value for restricted picklist field: "Wife". You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.

How shall I proceed?
Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Check if the picklist value Wife Exist or not in the field. It seems you are trying to add value which does not exist in the field

Comment: Make sure the value you're putting on your record for the picklist field matches the API name and not the label.

Answer (score 2):

When I've assigned the picklist item value to the variable, I shouldn't use any brackets "".
[image: var_assignation]

After removing them, it worked like a charm.
thanks for suggestion/help @drew-kennedy & @salesforce-Developer