# How To Update a Picklist Field From an Assignment Variable in a Flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, picklist

I've been struggling to update a picklist field in a record update in a flow and on running the solution past a few other developers today they were unsure what was blocking the update also.

In a record update I need to update two fields. One is a text field being updated without an assignment variable. The value is directly typed into the value box.
The second field is a picklist field which I'm trying to set it's value from a variable assignment.  I've tried this using variables of type Text and Picklist but neither work.  If I debug the flow the record being updated has the correct values from the assignment, therefore it seems it should work.
If I set the value of the picklist field by directly typing in the value in the value-setting instead of using the variable the field updates correctly.  When trying to use the variable for the value no error unlike the issue reported in [How update record picklist field from a variable in a flow?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/295172/how-update-record-picklist-field-from-a-variable-in-a-flow) There is no exception/error occuring.  The variable has been set to be allow it to be used for input and output outside the flow.  I've tried it without this also.

I've tried "Equals" variable and "Add" variable but neither work

Does anyone know why a variable which shows in a debug as if it is being set correctly for a record update does not actually work. Are there special considerations that need to be applied for assigning a variable to a picklist field?  The field is not a multi select picklist.

Thanks in advance for any tips on this
[image: Variable Definition]

[image: Assign Value on variable]

[image: Set Field in record update to variable]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add detail of the variable setting and record update elements from the flow. Screenshots are not brilliant from accessibility and searchability but would still help here.

Comment: Thanks @phil W. I've added screenshots now. I hope it helps.

Comment: So, you said it didn't work if the "flag" was defined as a "Picklist" (a set of choices with values and labels) instead of as a "Text"?

Comment: Hi Phil, Apologies, I've been debugging all day and have noted that the issue is in relation  to a Get Records query which is not retuning the expected value. I've been trying to get the Email Message associated to a Task based on the Activity Id on the Email Message matching the Task Id in an After insert on Task but the ActivityId seems to not be populated yet and therefore the value I am trying to assign to my variable which I then apply to my picklist has not been set correctly. Applying a value from a variable to the picklist field will work but not from the way I was hoping or expecting.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I guess it's a different issue therefore than for what I opened this question for. Should the question be closed somehow without an answer? Thanks everyone for your help & apologies for any confusion on this.

Comment: You can opt to delete the question if you want and raise a new one.

Comment: Thanks Phil W for your help